# Should I be concerned about the warning message in model.matrix.default() - non-list contrasts argument ignored?

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, contrasts, mgcv

I am running a GAMM (mgcv package) with percentage/proportion as the dependent variable and a mixture of categorical and continuous variables, after running most of my models, this is the warning message shown

```
Warning messages:
1: In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!
2: In model.matrix.default(~b$groups[[n.levels - i + 1]] - 1, contrasts.arg = c("contr.treatment",  :
non-list contrasts argument ignored
```

Should I be concerned about seeing the second (or first) warning message?
Below is my code and a subset of my data as well.

```
gamm.prov <- gamm(OV_percent/100~landuse+altitude+dist_to_water+bio_5+bio_6+bio_8+bio_13+bio_14, random=list(PROVINCE=~1), family=binomial, control=lmeControl(returnObject=TRUE, maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000, opt = "optim"), niterPQL=1000, data=dataov)
gamm.p.exp <- gamm(OV_percent/100~landuse+altitude+dist_to_water+bio_5+bio_6+bio_8+bio_13+bio_14, random=list(PROVINCE=~1), family=binomial, control=lmeControl(returnObject=TRUE, maxIter = 1000, msMaxIter = 1000, msMaxEval = 1000, opt = "optim"), niterPQL=1000, data=dataov, correlation=corExp(form=~LONG+LAT, nugget=T))
```

Subset of data

```
    LONG      LAT  PROVINCE OV_percent Year    bio_1   bio_10   bio_11 bio_12 bio_13 bio_14   bio_15 bio_16 bio_17
1 103.0695 16.53787 Khon Kaen       7.69 2007 26.89583 29.35000 23.53333   1139    211      2 85.81328    573     18
2 103.0908 16.75853 Khon Kaen      18.18 2007 26.58750 28.98333 23.30000   1151    220      2 86.79789    585     17
3 102.8113 16.26788 Khon Kaen      12.50 2007 27.02083 29.45000 23.70000   1129    217      2 83.21073    553     20
4 102.5762 15.98167 Khon Kaen      17.46 2007 27.05417 29.40000 23.81667   1080    212      2 80.34490    511     20
5 102.3275 16.69767 Khon Kaen       6.78 2007 26.45833 28.96667 22.85000   1043    213      2 84.25506    512     17
6 102.4431 15.80308 Khon Kaen       7.14 2007 27.11250 29.40000 24.01667   1029    207      3 78.97439    490     21
bio_18 bio_19    bio_2    bio_3    bio_4 bio_5 bio_6 bio_7    bio_8    bio_9 dist_to_water landuse altitude
1    405     18 9.708333 57.10784 239.2266  34.2  17.2  17.0 27.90000 23.53333     0.0372678      11      178
2    410     17 9.841667 58.58135 234.7448  33.7  16.9  16.8 27.61667 23.30000     0.2358495      11      231
3    396     20 9.891667 57.50969 236.3112  34.5  17.3  17.2 27.90000 23.70000     0.0506897      11      174
4    266     26 9.841666 57.89216 229.1631  34.5  17.5  17.0 27.86667 24.16667     0.1003466      12      183
5    356     19 9.533333 54.16666 251.6115  34.0  16.4  17.6 27.50000 23.31667     0.0372678      11      208
6    262     31 9.725000 58.58434 219.1629  34.5  17.9  16.6 27.26667 24.41667     0.0901388      11      188
```

There are no single values for any of the variables I'm using in the model. I've also factor(dataov$var_name) the categorical variables before including them in the model.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that _percentage_ should be modeled through a _binomial_ glm? The first error asks exactly that

Comment: @Nutle I divided the response variable by 100 so that it is a proportion, and from what I know, I can use family = binomial for proportions. Please do let me know if I should use some other model! Thanks

Comment: Technically you should be modelling integer counts with `family = binomial`; i.e. you supposed to pass it the counts and sample total counts (see `?binomial`). If you want to model proportions directly then `quasibinomial` would stop the warning. If the response doesn't come from a situation where you have an integer count from a sample total count, then assuming the response is conditionally distribution binomial may not be the right choice. A beta distribution is often used for continuous proportions.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Thanks for the comment! Will run using quasibinomial instead. Would that remove the second warning too by any chance?

EDIT: Does not remove the second warning

Comment: Not sure; that warning could be coming from anyone of three top-level functions (`nlme::lme()`, `MASS:glmmPQL()`, or `mgcv::gamm()`, or any of their support or helper functions.) In and of itself I don;t think the two warnings are related.